# Mariadb Docker Container Refuses to Initialize With Database Schema

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I am using the following docker-compose to initialize a database service, that will be used by the web service.

```
<!-- language: YAML -->
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: container-build/web/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
    - /home/johndoe/src/proj:/var/www/public_html
    links:
    - db

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4.7
    ports:
    - "6603:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345678
    - MYSQL_USER=dbuser
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=12345678

    volumes:
      - "mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql"
      - /home/johndoe/src/proj/data/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
volumes: 
   mysql_data: { driver: local }
```

I then build and run the containers as follows:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

As you see in the log, the database mydb is not initialized, as confirmed by running a shell inside the container and trying to access the database. So, no root user is created, no database is created and no schema is imported. Interestingly, though, the environment variables have been imported to the container, so they are available in the shell for the cotainer, e.g. echo $MYSQL_USER prints `dbuser`, which is what we defined in the docker-compose file.

```
<!-- language: plain -->
Recreating proj_db_1 ... done
Recreating proj_web_1 ... done
Attaching to proj_db_1, proj_web_1
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.4.7-MariaDB-1:10.4.7+maria~bionic) starting as process 1 ...
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.7 started; log sequence number 140016; transaction id 21
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@0d988a449cca' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190825  5:08:33
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:33 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1   | Version: '10.4.7-MariaDB-1:10.4.7+maria~bionic'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
web_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.19.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
web_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.19.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
web_1  | [Sun Aug 25 05:08:33.526373 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.2.21 configured -- resuming normal operations
web_1  | [Sun Aug 25 05:08:33.526419 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:46 8 [Warning] Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'172.19.0.3' (using password: YES)
web_1  | 172.19.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2019:05:08:46 +0000] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 402 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Safari/605.1.15"
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:47 9 [Warning] Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'172.19.0.3' (using password: YES)
web_1  | 172.19.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2019:05:08:47 +0000] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 401 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Safari/605.1.15"
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:08:49 10 [Warning] Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'172.19.0.3' (using password: YES)
web_1  | 172.19.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2019:05:08:49 +0000] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 401 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Safari/605.1.15"
db_1   | 2019-08-25  5:09:35 11 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Another evidence that shows docker-compose.yml is not doing what it's supposed to do is when I browse http://localhost:8080/test.php which has the following content:

```
<!-- language: php -->
<?php

echo "Testing database<br>";

try{
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydb;host=db', 'dbuser', '12345678');
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    return;
}
 ?>
```

And this page shows:

```
 <!-- language: plain -->
 Testing database
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'dbuser'@'172.19.0.3' (using password: YES)
```

On the other hand, running the mariadb image on the command line and passing those environment variables and the volume pointing to schema.sql to the command line works and initializes the database. For example, the following command works:

```
<!-- language: lang-bash -->
docker run --name mariadbtest  --rm -ti -d   -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345678" -e "MYSQL_USER=dbuser" -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=12345678  -v /home/johndoe/src/proj/data/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql  mariadb
```

So, what's wrong with my docker-compose.yml? There's a [YouTube](https://youtu.be/2ESAi2vq-80) video by [Adam Culp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/686775/adam-culp) that uses a very similar docker-compose.yaml.

Comment: try double quoting your mysql vars in docker-compose.yml

Comment: Didn't make a difference @DovRine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short Answer**:
Rename your data volume mapped to /var/lib/mysql i.e. rename mysql_data to db_data and run `docker-compose up` again.

**Long Answer**:

I figured out the issue eventually. The docker hub [page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) for MariaDB slightly touches on the fact that only when a container is created for the first time, is it initialized with the database schema available in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d.

> When a container is started for the first time, a new database with
>   the specified name will be created and initialized with the provided
>   configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with
>   extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order. You can easily populate your mariadb services by mounting a SQL
>   dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed
>   data. SQL files will be imported by default to the database specified
>   by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable.

This caused me to change db service name in docker-compose and re-run, which didn't work. I also removed all stopped containers with `docker container prune`, which didn't help either.

Finally, I thought there must be something constant in all my `docker-compose up`s, which had nothing to do with the service name. It was mysql_data volume container in docker-compose.yml. It seems to be a data layer that is not recreated when you redeploy and in my case it had been initialized wrong the first time I had run it, maybe because I had not provided environment variables. So, I changed the name to db_data and did a `docker-compose up` again and viola! This time the database was initialized and I was able to access the database tables I had introduced to the container in schema files when initializing.

Comment: no need to rename anything.
just remove existing volume `docker volume rm <volume-name>`.
to see all volumes: `docker volume ls`.

Comment: @dimaninc you should make your answer a full answer, yours is the only thing that worked for me! And probably people without volumes are ignoring that a previous stopped container may have created such a volume. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Héctor done, posted as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

just remove existing volume: `docker volume rm <volume-name>`

to see all volumes: `docker volume ls`